# Unable to get these 2 divs within one

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get these 2 lists to show within the header-top-bar div but cannot see what I am doing wrong. Right now the social media one is showing under the first one.

The css should be putting the 2 divs within the containing div. The first one should be to the left which it is. The 2nd one I am trying to put to the right edge.

```css
#header-top-bar {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 1178px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#contact-details-list {
  height: 22px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 801px;
}

ul#contact-details {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3px;
}

ul#contact-details li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 22px;
}

#social-media-links {
  height: 22px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 350px;
}

ul#social-media {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3px;
}

ul#social-media li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 22px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-top-bar">
  <div id="contact-details-list">
    <ul id="contact-details">
      <li class="li-phone">555-555-5555</li>
      <li class="li-email">email address</li>
      <li class="li-hours">Hours by appointment</li>
      <li class="li-location">address</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- contact-details-list -->
  <div id="social-media-links">
    <ul id="social-media">
      <li class="li-facebook">Facebook</li>
      <li class="li-youtube">Youtube</li>
      <li class="li-yelp">Yelp</li>
      <li class="li-google">Google+</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- social-media-links -->
</div>
<!-- header-top-bar -->
```

Comment: Nothing in your code appear to be attempting to make `#contact-details-list` and `#social-media-links` be side-by-side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `display: inline-block;` in your `#contact-details-list` and `#social-media-links`.

So it'll be like:

```
 #contact-details-list {
   display: inline-block;
   height: 22px;
   position: relative;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0;
   margin: 0;
   width: 801px;
 }

 #social-media-links {
   display: inline-block;
   height: 22px;
   position: relative;
   bottom: 0px;
   right: 0;
   margin: 0;
   width: 350px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use display: flex in #header-top-bar instead of inline-block, it's a best practice.

```
#header-top-bar {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1178px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yxrVRP